# Making a randomly generated division sum that always results in a whole number?

Tags: division

I am currently making a random math quiz which generates random addition, subtraction, and multiplication fine. Those 3 are simple. I would like to know just how to make a randomly generated division question that always equals a whole number, using 2 int variables,  num1 and num2 but I just cannot figure it out Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code we can look at? I would probably generate num1 first and then generate num2 based on the value of num1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be pretty simple. The logic may go like this:

- Randomly generate a number and call it **divisor**
- Multiply your **divisor** with a randomly generated number and call it **dividend**

Now you've got two integer numbers (dividend & divisor) that should solve into a whole number **quotient**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would construct the the two integers using a pool of random generated factors, making sure the two have at least one factor in common. Or to make it even simpler, pick a random integer `n`, then multiply it by another random integer `m` and show the division `m*n/n`.